# Selecting elements using LINQ-to-XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<games>
  <game id="123456" name="501">
    <player id="1">
      <name>john</name>
      <score>495</score>
      <movesLeft>15</movesLeft>
      <won>No</won>
      <completed>uncompleted</completed>
    </player>
    <player id="2">
      <name>
         konj
      </name>
      <score>501</score>
      <movesLeft>15</movesLeft>
      <won>No</won>
      <completed>uncompleted</completed>
    </player>
  </game>
</games>
```

and I create this query, but it does not compile:

```
string path = @"D:\xml\dartDatabase.xml";
XElement file = XElement.Load(path);

var query = from f in file.Element("games").Elements("game")
            where (string)f.Attribute("id") == "123"
            select (string)f.Element("name");
```

It underlines the first line (around `from` section), saying the error is:

> 'Where' not found, are you missing a reference to System.Core.dll or using directive for System.Linq

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks, that was stupid of me. I added XLinq, and figured that is enough.

Comment: I returned to this project after a while, but never got around one problem. This query never executes, when i tried to used i get `NullReferenceException`. 
`I tried 
Console.WriteLine(query.ToString);
`
but it never gets there. What is the problem with this query, i still use above xml file.

Comment: `f.Element("name") is `null`, since the `<game>` tag only contains `<player>` elements.